# Rails client IP ::1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to fetch client IP from Rails, but when I am testing this on my local machine I get `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

I have tried the following two approaches in my controller:

`request.remote_addr`

`request.remote_ip`

Trying on Rails 5 beta3 if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is IP V6 Localhost/127.0.0.1

Comment: In general: you can't. IPv6 has a much bigger address space than IPv4, so there is mapping. There are some IPv6 IPs which are equivalent to IPv4 ones but you can not do this for all of them.

Comment: Rails defines [`ActionDispatch::Request::LOCALHOST`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e595d91ac2c07371b441f8b04781e7c03ac44135/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L26), one might consider using it for comparison.

Comment: mudasobwa: well, if you want to find out if request is from local, then you can use request.local?